# Styling with sld in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I am using geoserver to serve my shapefile data, and I use SLD as the style solution.

There are two fields in the data related to styling: `type` and `status`. The `type` field contains values like `highway` `freeway` `parkway` and etc. The `status` filed contains values like `planning` `building` `completed`.

Different arrangement of the type and status should result in different style, as shown in this table:

[image]

There are 9 rules for the style. Furthermore, the zoom level should be considered while styling, say I have 4 different rules related to the zoom level, there will be `9*4  = 36` rules finally.

Once there are new `type` values added, the number of rules will increase too.

I wonder how do you handle this kind of situation ?

Comment: You could do it with CSS (but read http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/cascading.html) or generate it with some other offline tool.

Comment: I second what BradHards says.  The CSS extension is much easier than coding SLD by hand.  It is not installed by default, so you need to download the extension first

Comment: CSS will give you a significant boost if the attributes are controlling independent properties, like, for example, if type controls color and status controls width, or something like that, as you can set them in independent rules and CSS will create the mixes for you. If instead each combination needs a unique, irregular styling, you'll have to create many rules, but it will still be less work to write.

Answer (score 3):

The way SLD works, you'll need a bunch of filters like:

`type=highway AND status=planning` (This is pseudo code, you need to use the [SLD Filter Expressions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html#filter-expressions).)

As BradHards says, the [CSS Styling Extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/index.html) is a good way to make this easier.

If you only have to do it once, and you're happy to do it the long way, but more easily than hand-coding SLD, I use QGIS to set up my styles and then export to SLD. This gets you about 80% of the way there. You'll need to fix up any unhandled situations and maybe tweak things. Make sure you keep the QGIS styles simple!

Comment: I have tried qgis, but the sld generated by qgis can not be completely recognized by geoserver

Comment: As I said, @giser, you can get 80% of the way there with QGIS. In terms of creating the big complex list you're after, I think you'll find it easier with QGIS than doing the SLD by hand! CSS is a very valid alternative, and may be better.